# How to define character sets to mix in Code 128 barcodes in Active Reports 2.0?

Tags: activereports, componentone, code128

I am using ActiveReports 2.0 (Visual Basic 6.0). Is it possible to implement this functionality:

> **Mix code sets in the 128 bar code**.

I need to encode a USPS tracking number. Following is an example of the same:

CJ123456789US as **Code 128B**: "CJ1″

then shift to **Code 128C**: "23456789″

then shift to **Code 128B**: "US"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not supported as of now. However, it has already been been forwarded to the concerned team as an enhancement request.

You may refer to the following forum post for further follow up:
http://our.componentone.com/groups/topic/how-to-define-character-sets-to-mix-in-code-128-barcodes-5/

Regards,
Mohita